# Mongo DB - Deep populate not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a project that uses Node & Mongoose/ Mongo DB and i'm having trouble doing a deep populate on one of my models.

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate) plugin to manage my deep population. Here the setup in my controller:

```
const board = await Board.find({'_id':boardId}).deepPopulate('members.id')
```

Here is an image of my stored DB board value in compass:

[image]

The id's in the property 'id' in the members array are that of user ID's. What I would like is to populate 'id' with the users details. The error message i'm getting at the moment is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined

Here is my board schema:

```
const boardSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:'Please enter a board name'
    },
    owner:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
  },
    members:{
    type:Array,
  }     
});

boardSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
```

Not entirely sure why it's not populating here?

Comment: Maybe because you have not defined how to populate? `members` is just an array. You can try defining the schema of object that this array will hold.

Comment: Ok would that mean replacing the members type of array with a nested object that has the ref of the scheme I want to populate?

Comment: Pretty much yes, from the image I assume there are two props `privilege` and `id`. Just define a sub schema for this two props and put it inside like `members: [{  privilege: <def>, id: <def> }]`, where `<def>` is the definition for that prop.

Comment: Worked like a treat, if you want to post this as the answer ill mark it as correct

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the schema for the members array too, only then mongoose will know how to populate it.

```
 members: [{
     privilege: String,
     id: {
         type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
         ref:'User' // assuming its an user
     },
 }],
```

Comment: Bonus question, if I populate this and then make edits to it and .save() it, will MongoDB still just save it as a reference ie ObjectId(123asd) or will it save the entire populated object?

Comment: Do you mean calling the `.save()` on parent object or populated subdoc?

Comment: With my await function above (first line) if I modified the boards object after populating it and then called boards.save() would it save in my DB a reference to my members.id or the whole populated document of members.id?

Comment: I have not tried is myself, so I can't give any definite answer on that. However, my assumption is it should not save the whole sub doc, as that does not make any sense and breaks the whole populate feature. I will spin up some sample code to find the answer.